# why <div> container does not limit the size of the element within it?

Tags: html, css

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="ru">
    <head>
        <meta charset="UTF-8">
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="styles.css">
    </head>
    <body>
        <div class="root">
            <div class="conteiner">
                <img src="https://b2b.ostrovok.ru/wp-content/uploads/2022/01/1-2.jpg" class = "image">
            </div>
        </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

why if I write like this, the image changes its size:

```
.image {
    width: 30vw;
}
```

but if I try to resize the div container nothing changes

```
.conteiner {
    width: 30vw;
}
```

in my opinion, the container should limit the size of the element in it

Comment: `.conteiner { overflow-x: hidden; }` will limit the size of the image if you change the `.container { width: ...; }`

Comment: you can also apply `width: 100%` to `.image` and then changing the `width` of `.conteiner` will adjust the `width` of `.image`

Comment: If there is no size definition for an image (in CSS), it will be displayed at its original size, regardless of the size of any container. However, if you define `width: 100%; height: auto;` for the image, it will have the width of the container, and the height will be adjusted according to the original width/height proportions of the image.

Answer (score -2):

Yes, in this other question you can find more information: [How to fit a image in div wather image size is max then div or min then div](https://stackoverflow.com/q/11133560/12508080)

You could do something like this:

```
.conteiner {
  width: 30vw;
}

.conteiner .image {
  width: inherit;
}
```